# Can you use a second balloon?

Tags: breathedge

I've managed to find the necessary supplies to make another balloon, and I'm not aware of any other uses for one of the items, so I made a second balloon ... but it won't let me equip it.

Is there some other upgrade that I need to make before I can use it, or did I just waste some supplies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that someone has posted a video :

So no, you can't use a second balloon, but you *can* get a blueprint for a 'double balloon'.  View the video for the spoiler on where to get it.

And yes, I wasted my resources.